# How save a base64 image as file in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, html2canvas

i can't save a base64 image as file by controller and don't get any errors, i don't want to save in db, just in public folder.

i'm using Rails 4.2.8 and Ruby 2.1, it's a legacy app, and html2canvas to generate base64 image.

my controller def:

```
def save_image
  image = params[:image]
  file = "#{Rails.root}/public/dashboard.png"
  File.open(file,'wb') do |f|
    f.write Base64.decode64(image)
  end
  file.save
end
```

i try using a Tempfile and using now an existing file, and "image = request.body['image']", both not work.

route:

```
post 'save_image' => 'intranet/dashboard#save_image'
```

and i call the post req in html2canvas function:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('list')).then(canvas => {
        base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
        var url = '/save_image';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                image : base64String
            }
        });
      });
```

don't have any alert on logs and i don't know how debug this.

Comment: first determine if the problem is in the client or server. Use Chrome devtools to inspect the post request and see if the data is being sent. Use development log to see what's received. Then use debugger statements on the server to see how the received data is being processed.

Comment: app log shows that base64 is being send by params and google devtools too, in server log just show the post req. I think the problem is in the processing of the controller.

Comment: Does the `params[:image]` string include a header, like `data:image/png;base64,`? If that is the case, then you will need to remove that header and only decode the actual image data part. That means `Base64.decode64(image.split(',').last)` might work for you. But you need to check, of course, if the uploaded file is a png or something else before writing it into the file.

Comment: Yes, it's a png file and include this header, i try this code to remove but still wrong, don't save the file, could be something about permissions?

Comment: If there was a permission issue, then an exception should be raised. Did you take a look at the log file of your application? What do the log entries look like that are written to the log file when the application receives the request?

Comment: Btw. `file.save` line doesn't make any sense in your method. Just remove it. In its current version, that line will raise an error that there is no `save` method for the string ".../public/dashboard.png"

Comment: the app log return "INFO -- : Started POST "/save_image" for ip at 2023-08-07 13:24:45 -0300
INFO -- : Processing by Intranet::DashboardController#save_image as TEXT INFO -- :   Parameters: {"image"=>"data:image/png;base64,..."

Comment: what exception type can be add to resolve?

Comment: The `save_image` method you show in your question is not being called, otherwise you'd be seeing an exception ```NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for ".../public/dashboard.png"```. Maybe you have another `save_image` method defined after the one you think you're hitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve with this:

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:save_image]
```